# ¿Porqué mi código se ejecuta desordenadamente?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

estoy aprendiendo a usar node js, y me eh percatado que mi código no se ejecuta con el orden correcto, mi código está así:

```
async function Marcas_proceso(marcas) {
var add_marca = [];
marcas.forEach(element => {
    axios(curl.curl_syscom('get', `marcas/${element}/productos`))
        .then(function (response) {
            if(response.data.cantidad > 0){
               add_marca.push(element) 
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {

        })
});
console.log(add_marca); 
}
```

El resultado de que envía es este: `[]` o sea se ejecuta primero el console.log() y después todo lo demás, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal? Saludos.

Comment: Tu código es asíncrono, tal como indicaste con la palabra reservada `async`. Poner código sin saber qué significa puede llevar a resultados inesperados, tal como acabas de descubrir. Cuando se trabaja en asíncrono, JS va a lanzar cada llamada asíncrona en un nuevo hilo y tras lanzarlas, va a continuar ejecutando tu código actual. Es decir, lanzará el GET y tras ello seguirá ejecutando tu código (el console.log() en este caso) **sin esperar a que terminen las llamadas asíncronas**. Investiga cómo trabajar con promesas si quieres usar axios, es muy diferente a trabajar de manera "normal".

Comment: @Benito puedes escribirlo como respuesta? No te tomará mucho tiempo. El solo pregunta por qué sucede lo que sucede. Si quieres puedes ahondar más en la explicación.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Técnicamente ya está usando promesas... Axios te devuelve una promesa :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código es asíncrono, tal como indicaste con la palabra reservada async. Cuando se trabaja en asíncrono, JS va a lanzar cada llamada asíncrona en un nuevo hilo y tras lanzarlas, va a continuar ejecutando tu código actual. Es decir, lanzará el GET y tras ello seguirá ejecutando tu código (el console.log() en este caso) **sin esperar a que terminen las llamadas asíncronas**.

Hay múltiples maneras de evitar esto pero sinceramente, creo que la mejor manera es aprender a trabajar en asíncrono y evitamos andar poniendo `await` por todas partes, que además hará que todo sea más lento puesto que no podrán hacerse llamadas en paralelo. Así pues, aprovechemos la capacidad de JS de trabajar en paralelo y *abracemos la asincronía*!

PS: Nunca hagas una promesa sin controlar que pueda romperse... a nadie le gusta romper una promesa, pero a veces sucede. Añade siempre el `.catch(reason => {/* HAZ ALGO CON TU ERROR AQUÍ */})` después del `.then(...)`!

```js
// Primero que nada añado un método que me permita obtener las promesas, en tu caso usarás las llamadas a Axios
const axios = (value) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 100, `Respuesta a la llamada con parámetro: ${value}`))

async function Marcas_proceso(marcas) {

  // Creamos un array donde vamos a guardar las promesas
  const promises = [];
  // Recorremos el parámetro igual que antes
  marcas.forEach(element => {
    // Pero en vez de hacer algo con el... simplemente guardamos en nuestro array la llamada a Axios
    promises.push(axios(element));
  });

  // Ahora usamos Promises.all, que hará que se ejecuten todas las promesas
  Promise.all(promises)
  // Si todo va bien, tendremos nuestra respuesta en el value
    .then(value => {
      // En mi caso es un array con 3 strings, en tu caso serán las respuestas de las llamadas GET!
      console.log(value);
    });
}

// Invocamos el método
Marcas_proceso([1,2,3]);
```

Es un ejemplo sencillo pero creo que te será fácil adaptarlo a tu caso.

Comment: gracias ya me funciono

Comment: @AngelCab Si la respuesta te ayudó no olvides marcarla como aceptada :)

Comment: listo marcado .